# Http tunnel sample

Tags: c++, delphi, http, tunnel

Is it possible to create an HTTP tunnel in Delphi or C++?

My application connects to several HTTP servers that do not belong to the company I work for. Because of that, our users need to open their firewall ports to allow those connections. I thought about creating a tunnel at my company and redirecting HTTP requests made by my application through this tunnel. This way, my clients will only need to open one port and the tunnel will handle all requests. All requests are made with POST or GET using indy components.

**EDIT:** I can't use an HTTP proxy. Some of my users have already got their own HTTP proxy and it is going to be impossible to connect to two different proxy servers at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like all you need is a simple *proxy server*. No need to write any code yourself.

Comment: Nops .. my clients can have their own proxy servers also.

Comment: So you want to write a proxy server?  If you don't want to use a proxy type server, your customers will not be able to use your tunnel system for anything other than a single hostname per tunnel. Your question is very poorly defined, and is basically unanswerable as it stands.  You are smart enough to edit it. So please add more detail on how you think it could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free component is kind of old but it works you can get yourself inspired from there

[TGpHTTPProxy](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/tgphttpproxy.htm)

Or you can try this samples

https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/examplesocks4proxybyaphex

https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/multi-threadedhttpproxyserver

Answer (score 1):

As Warren P. and Rob Kennedy suggest, you really just need a proxy server. Don't write a tunnel yourself, it's a huge overkill and it's far from easy (writing a robust socket application is more time consuming than it first appears to be).

If you want something dead simple look for `datapipe.c` or netcat (`nc`) unix command. SSH can create tunnels too (look in OpenSSH and PuTTy docs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free open source HTTP-Tunnel and UDP-Tunnel: http://barbatunnel.codeplex.com/

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a library/API that can be used from C++ there.